# Using eexists to construct record terms in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose there is a denary relation `R` over some type `A`.

```
Variable A : Type.
Variable R : A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> A -> Prop.
```

`X` and `Y` are slightly different propositions which both assert that `R` holds over some 10 terms of type `A`.

```
Inductive X : Prop :=
| X_intro : forall a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9, 
R a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 -> X. 

Record Y : Prop :=
{ a0 : A; a1 : A; a2 : A; a3 : A; a4 : A;
  a5 : A; a6 : A; a7 : A; a8 : A; a9 : A;
  RY : R a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 }.
```

Since `X` and `Y` assert the same things, it should be easy to prove `X -> Y`. We could, for instance, do it by explicitly constructing a proof of `Y`.

```
Theorem XY : X -> Y.
inversion 1. exists a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 
a5 a6 a7 a8 a9. apply H0. Qed.
```

But this seems unnecessary. The last proposition obtained by `inversion` on premise completely determines the 10 terms, so we shouldn't have to spell their names out. We could postpone their identification with `eexists` and unify them later.

```
Theorem XY' : X -> Y.
intro. eexists. inversion H. apply H0.
```

But unification fails here. This is what my goals look like before `apply H0`:

```
H0 : R a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9

======================== ( 1 / 1 )
R ?46 ?47 ?48 ?49 ?50 ?51 ?52 ?53 ?54 ?55
```

All arguments to `R` are undetermined, so it should be possible to unify `?46` with `a0`, `?47` with `a1`, and so on. Why does it fail?

Comment: In the future: please minimize your test case, e.g. I'm sure a trinary relation would have been enough. Further, please don't refer to automatically generated names like `H0`. It makes it hard for users with different Coq versions to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you get is something along the lines of:

> unable to unify "?a0" with "a0" (cannot instantiate "?a0" because "a0"
>   is not in its scope)

This is a fairly common error. Let me explain it with a simple example.

Let's start by defining an inductive data type that wraps a value of type `A`:

```
Variable A : Type.

Inductive Box :=
| elem : A -> Box.
```

Next, let's define a theorem about this data type which states that if you have a box, then there exists an element that is equal to the thing in the box:

```
Theorem boxOk (b:Box) : exists a, match b with elem a' => a = a' end.
```

We can try to prove this your way:

```
  eexists.
  destruct b.
  Fail reflexivity.
Restart.
```

But `reflexivity` fails, with the dreaded error message:

> Unable to unify "?a" with "a" (cannot instantiate  "?a"
>   because "a" is not in its scope: available arguments are 
>   "elem a").

So what happens here? The term that these tactics construct looks like the following:

```
ex_intro _ ?a (match b with elem a => eq_refl end).
```

And you are now asking Coq to fill in `?a` with `a`, which cannot work because `a` is not defined in the scope of `?a`. *The most common problem with this error is that `eexists` was called too early.*

So instead, we should `destruct` first, and then call `eexists`. And it works:

```
  destruct b.
  eexists.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The term that these tactics construct looks like the following:

```
match b with elem a => (ex_intro _ ?a eq_refl) end.
```

And now `a` is in `?a`'s scope and can easily be filled in.

In your example, you should do the following (which is actually what you did in your manual proof).

```
Theorem XY' : X -> Y.
  intro h. 
  inversion h as [? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? h'].
  eexists. 
  apply h'.
Qed.
```